# Convert enum of Objective-c to enum of Android

Tags: java, android, objective-c, enums

Anybody help me please. I want to convert Objective-c enum to android enum like below:

```
// Objective-c enum
===================
typedef enum{
  ab = 0,
  bc = 1,
  ca = 2
}PieceType;

// just print using android Logcat:
=================
Log("ab = ", ab+"");
Log("bc = ", bc+"");
Log("ca = ", ca+"");
================

Result: 
ab = 0;
bc = 1;
ca = 2;
```

Want to convert enumeration above to the android enumeration but keep the same result when printing.

Comment: Where did you struggle when you Googled for Java enum?

Comment: I see the Objective-c using just like "PieceType.ab" it will receive the value of ab is 0, and I want to know android can do like this or not. For android, it needs another method to get enum value. I don't know it can have anyway to do like Objective-c or not. Anyway, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
public enum PieceType{
    AB(0), BC(1), CA(2);
    private int value;

    private Currency(int value) {
            this.value = value;
    }
};
```

and here a link for you:

http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

In a future, try to read reference [`Enum Types`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) before asking.

Here is example:

```
public enum Example {
   AB(0), BC(1), CA(2);

   private int val;

   private Example(int c) {
       val = c;
   }

   public int getData() {
       return val;
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
int value = Example.AB.getData();
```

Comment: Yes, I had read already, but I see the Objective-c just using just like "Example.AB" it will receive the value of AB is 0, and I want to know android can do like this or not. I just see like your code above also. Anyway, thank you a lot.